# Como concatenar esse js

Tags: jquery

???    Como concatenar esse js, não to conseguindo da erro

```
 success:function(res) {
            secreto = res.lat;
            secreto2= res.lon;
            cidade = res.city;
            Pais  = res.country;

window.location.href = "secreto.php?lat='+secreto+'&long='+secreto2";

}
```

Não to conseguindo

Answer (score 2):

É simples, você usa OU aspas simples OU aspas duplas:

```
window.location.href = "secreto.php?lat=" + secreto + "&long=" + secreto2;
```

Existem casos em que você precisa de aspas (simples ou duplas) no resultado, aí sim você usa uma dentro da outra.

Comment: Opa, Muito Obrigado!